# How to remove dark layer on video from BMPLayer iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview

I want to remove dark layer from BMPlayer. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I found right answer:

```
player.controlView.mainMaskView.isHidden = true
```

and use it like this:

```
func bmPlayer(player: BMPlayer, playerIsPlaying playing: Bool) {
    print("| BMPlayerDelegate | playerIsPlaying | playing - \(playing)")
    player.controlView.mainMaskView.isHidden = true
}

func bmPlayer(player: BMPlayer, playerStateDidChange state: BMPlayerState) {
    print("| BMPlayerDelegate | playerStateDidChange | state - \(state)")
    player.controlView.mainMaskView.isHidden = true
}

func bmPlayer(player: BMPlayer, playTimeDidChange currentTime: TimeInterval, totalTime: TimeInterval) {
    player.controlView.mainMaskView.isHidden = true
}

func bmPlayer(player: BMPlayer, loadedTimeDidChange loadedDuration: TimeInterval, totalDuration: TimeInterval) {
    player.controlView.mainMaskView.isHidden = true
}
```